# How to "at now" on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, at

Is there a way to run `at` immediately on FreeBSD?

On Ubuntu, when I run a script with "at now" it runs immediately. With FreeBSD, there is a delay because at is running through crontab. Default is 5m.

```
*/5     *        *       *       *       root    /usr/libexec/atrun
```

I changed it to run every 1m.

```
*/1     *        *       *       *       root    /usr/libexec/atrun
```

1m is still quite the long wait. Is there anyway to run `at` immediately on FreeBSD like I am able to on Ubuntu?

*edit*: Here is the code I am using to run the `at` command. `at now` runs immediately on Ubuntu, but does not on FreeBSD. I have no idea how to figure out how `at` is running on Ubuntu, but FreeBSD it is running on crontab scheduling causing the delay.

```
shell_exec("echo /usr/local/bin/php -q scripts/myfile.php {$var1} {$var2} | at now");
```

*edit*: Trying to run atrun immediately after manually (instead of waiting for cron) produces the following error.

```
atrun: setegid failed: Operation not permitted
```

I'm not sure how to fix that either in terms of giving the user permission to run it's own scheduled commands.

Comment: if you want to run immediately, why are you using `cron` or `at` ? Why not just run it from the command line ? If you want it to run when you are not logged in anymore you can run it using `nohup` and in the background, such as `nohup /path/to/myprogram & 2>&1` this will send the `stdin` and `stderr`, both to `nohup.out` file located in the directory you run the program from.

Comment: @MelBurslan `nohup` doesn't work for my usage. I am running the command in PHP. When using `at`, I get a return immediately. When using `nohup`, PHP sits and waits for the command to finish executing which leaves the page hanging. I'll edit the OP to show my usage.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete

Answer (score 1):

## Ampersand is your friend

Please, do not run with scissors. You are asking a very valid questions for all the wrong reasons.

`at` uses `cron` to schedule jobs in the future. They are great tools for that purpose. But when you are using scheduling tools to get things done now you are crossing the water to fill the bucket. MelBurslan points this out to you and gives you the proper answer. You then try to clarify your need - but unfortunately miss his point. You insist on using `at` - when you should simply use ampersand `&`.

For other readers - the question is more along the lines of "How do I get php to run (spawn) another script and continue without waiting for the script to finish?".

This will then lead you to some great fundamental unix knowledge as MelBurslan shows you:

```
nohup /path/to/myprogram & 2>&1
```

- `nohup` ensures that the command will keep running in the background even if the current user logs out.
- `&` is what you probably is missing: Ampersand disconnects the process and send it to the background.
- `2>&1` joins `stderr` (2) with `stdout` (1) and `nohup` then implicitly sends the output to `nohup.out`

If you do not add the ampersand - then the caller (here php) will wait until the job has finished.

If you then go down the rabbit hole as cas [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019867/is-there-a-way-to-use-shell-exec-without-waiting-for-the-command-to-complete) - you can then see how people are using this technique with `shell_exec` and `exec` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec))

Additional important information to understand from this:

If you are not interested in any output you can send it to `/dev/null` like this:

```
> /dev/null
```

This will redirect `stdout`. If you do not want any error messages as well you can redirect `stderr` like this:

```
 2> /dev/null
```

You can combine them into one line:

```
 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

And there is a short form of this - send stderr to stdout - and send stdout to "nothing":

```
  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

#### So let us put this knowledge into usage:

Your example misuses `at`:

```
shell_exec("echo /usr/local/bin/php -q scripts/myfile.php {$var1} {$var2} | at now");
```

But if you simply want it to continue your script - simply add the ampersand `&`

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/php -q scripts/myfile.php {$var1} {$var2} &");
```

If you do not use any output - then you should redirect it.

```
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/php -q scripts/myfile.php {$var1} {$var2} > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

And the most elegant version as suggested by Brent Braisley would be:

```
exec("nohup /usr/bin/php -q scripts/myfile.php {$var1} {$var2}  > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

## Excessive use of at

The `at` command schedules commands to be run by the `atrun` script.

If you read the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=at) for `at` you will find:

```
 Note that at is implemented through the cron(8) daemon by calling
 atrun(8) every five minutes.  This implies that the granularity of at
 might not be optimal for every deployment.  If a finer granularity is
 needed, the system crontab at /etc/crontab needs to be changed.
```

You have already adjusted the crontab. I would advise against it in your case. But if you insist you should look at [man crontab (5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5):

```
   string        meaning
   ------        -------
   @reboot       Run once, at startup of cron.
   @yearly       Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
   @annually     (same as @yearly)
   @monthly      Run once a month, "0   0 1 * *".
   @weekly       Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
   @daily        Run once a day, "0 0   * * *".
   @midnight     (same as @daily)
   @hourly       Run once an hour, "0   * * * *".
   @every_minute Run once a minute, "*/1 * * * *".
   @every_second Run once a second.
```

This means that you can change `*/1` (for once a minute) to `@every_second`.

But - please - don't :-)

## Running atrun manually

You should not misuse `atrun` as you suggest. "All" it does (in your context) is adding the ampersand `&` to execute you job in the background.

The most likely reason it fails is that you (as you should be!) are logged in as a regular user. Only root have permission to use `at` per default. If you need to change this - have a look at the man page for at and:

```
 /var/at/at.allow        allow permission control
 /var/at/at.deny         deny permission control
```

But - again - please - don't :-)

## If all fails...

If all fails then please restate your question. Getting the scheduling tool to run *now* is not the root cause of your problem. If the above is not enough - then we need to dig deeper.